# Using "in" keyword with maps in JS

Tags: javascript, hashmap

```
let hMap = new Map();
    
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        let diff = target - nums[i];
        
        if(diff in hMap)
           return [hMap[diff], i];
        hMap[nums[i]] = i;
    }
```

How does `if(diff in hMap)` work? I tried replacing it with hMap.has(diff) but that didn't work.

Comment: That code is using `Map` instances totally wrong - it could have used any object for that. It seems the author didn't know what they're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Maps are special kinds of objects, and objects can have arbitrary key-value pairs associated with them. Here, the `hMap` being used is being used *only* for its functionality as a plain object - an association of (object property) keys to values. It is *not* being used as a `Map`, so the code is understandably confusing.

The code would work just as well (and would make a lot more sense) if it was:

```
let hMap = {};
```

At this point, it should be pretty easy to understand what's going on: `hMap[nums[i]] = i;` sets a property on the object, and `diff in hMap` checks if the property exists on the object.

If one wanted to use Maps for this exercise, it would be appropriate only if one was using the Map methods to get and set values, which are completely different from that of normal objects:

```
if (hMap.has(diff)) {
  return [hMap.get(diff), i];
}
hMap.set(nums[i]), i;
```

You cannot use `in` to check if a Map has a property (set by `Map.set`) - you can only use `Map.has` for that.

Similarly, you cannot use `has` to check if a Map or other expression (or anything else) has a property *set by `expression[prop] = someValue`* - to look up such a `prop`, you have to use `in`.

Comment: I completely understand it now. Thank you for the explaination. This clears it up. Thank You.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in seting and getting a map entry.

To add value with a key you need to call method

`Map.set(key, value);`

To get value from Map by key you need to call method

`var value = Map.get(key);`

You code snippet can be like that:

```
let hMap = new Map();
    
for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    let diff = target - nums[i];
        
    if(hMap.has(diff)) return [hMap.get(diff), i];

    hMap.set(nums[i]) = i;
}
```